# Return Column heading in table, after looking up row and values in row

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have the table below. I want to lookup the column header a number is between numbers based on the name in column A. So, if I look up "Dog" and "3.5" then I want it to return "B". The best formula I have come up with is

```
=INDEX(L1:M6,COLUMN(INDEX(A1:G5,MATCH(J2,A1:A5,0),MATCH(J3,B2:G2,-1))),2)
```

However, it's not working great. First, I had to create a separate table to indicate the column returned to get the column header. Also, I can't figure out how to make it change the row it looks the number in. Third, i can only make it work using the number in the row as the upper bound ex. "3.5" returns "#N/A" instead of "B".

[image]

```
=INDEX(L1:M6,COLUMN(INDEX(A1:G5,MATCH(J2,A1:A5,0),MATCH(J3,B2:G2,-1))),2)
```

I want to return "B", not "#N/A". Also I want it not have to rely on the first index function. Ideally the formula looks something like this?

```
=INDEX(A1:G5,MATCH(J2,A1:A5,0),MATCH(J3,B2:G2,-1))
```

Comment: Try using `XLOOKUP()` --> `=XLOOKUP(J3,XLOOKUP(J2,A2:A5,B2:G5),B1:G1,,1,-1)`

Comment: `=INDEX(B1:G1,,MATCH(J3,INDEX(B2:G5,MATCH(J2,A2:A5,0),0),1))`

Comment: I missed they want the next value.  Adding 1 does not work when the match is exact.  `3` will return `B` and not `A`

Comment: But one can do:  `=INDEX(B1:G1,,XMATCH(J3,INDEX(B2:G5,MATCH(J2,A2:A5,0),0),1,-1))`

Comment: Or using only pre Excel 365:  `=INDEX(B1:G1,,MATCH(J3,INDEX(B2:G5,MATCH(J2,A2:A5,0),0),1)+ISERROR(MATCH(J3,INDEX(B2:G5,MATCH(J2,A2:A5,0),0),0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `XLOOKUP()` function here:

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(J3,XLOOKUP(J2,A2:A5,B2:G5),B1:G1,,1,-1)
```

---

Comment: @H00sier glad to know it worked. But as an alternative for older versions refer the solutions posted by Scott Craner Sir if you have which I wasn't sure and inadvertently used `XLOOKUP()`